# Reset blur property in css / html

Tags: javascript, html, css, filter, blur

My question is how can I put an image with a filter: blur, for later, changing the cursor for a div, and hiding it with cursor: none; and with a backdrop-filter, you can "remove" that blur, being able to sharpen the images by passing the div over them. PS: "Hover does not work because just by passing a little the image is already affected by the entire property, that is why I have to use backdrop-filter"

My code:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + (e.pageY - 50) + "px; left: " + (e.pageX - 50) + "px;");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /*Como no se puede poner un blur negativo, intente resetearlo cambiando el -5 por un 0, pero tampoco funciono*/
  backdrop-filter: blur(-5px);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(-5px);
}

.peces img {
  height: 15vh;
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="peces" id="uno"><img src="images/01.png"></div>
  <div class="peces" id="dos"><img src="images/02.png"></div>
  <div class="peces" id="tres"><img src="images/03.png"></div>
  <div class="peces" id="cuatro"><img src="images/03.png"></div>

  <div class="cursor"></div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for your answers =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use svg for this thing. Unfortunately I don't know if any better way exists.

```js
$('.pic').mousemove(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var upX = event.clientX;
    var upY = event.clientY;
    var mask = $('#mask1 circle')[0];
    mask.setAttribute("cy", (upY - 5) + 'px');
    mask.setAttribute("cx", (upX) + 'px');
});


$('.pic').mousemove(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var upX = event.clientX;
    var upY = event.clientY;
    var mask = $('#mask1 circle')[0];
    mask.setAttribute("cy", (upY - 5) + 'px');
    mask.setAttribute("cx", (upX) + 'px');
});
```

```css
.pic {
    height:600px;
}
.blur {
    height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
svg image{
  width:350px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pic">
    <svg class="blur" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%">
        <image filter="url(#filter2)" xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/EJOjIMC_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" ></image>
        <filter id="filter2">
            <fegaussianblur stdDeviation="5" />
        </filter>
        <mask id="mask1">
            <circle cx="-50%" cy="-50%" r="80" fill="white" filter="url(#filter2)" />
        </mask>
        <image xlink:href="https://i.imgur.com/EJOjIMC_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand" mask="url(#mask1)"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
```